# In Spritekit, is there a way to handle touch event on a temporarily created SKSpriteNode variable?

Tags: objective-c, events, sprite-kit, touch, sprite

I want to detect touch and react upon it, when a sprite is touched, but I don't want it to be covered using its own class (and thus, handled in touchesBegan method). I just want it to be considered as another sprite on the scene. I am currently doing it this way:

```
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:location];

if(touchedNode == self.AnswerButton) {
    NSLog(@"ANSWER button pressed.");
    return;
}

if(touchedNode == self.HangupButton) {
    NSLog(@"HANGUP button pressed.");
    [self hangUp];
    return;
}
```

But, I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to access the touch on self.HangupButon and self.AnswerButton child sprites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have it nailed down, without having to subclass.

Logic is:

1) Touch scene
2) Determine Node
3) Process based on node touched.

The only thing I would maybe do different is make this a separate function and add else to the second if (If this was Swift I would say use a switch)

Answer (score 0):

A tap gesture recognizer added to the sprite might be what you are looking for.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/

Comment: Views and Nodes are 2 different things,  you can't add the recognizer directly to the sprite,  he  would  have to add it to the view. then add the recognizer delegate to the scene,  then determine where in the scene it was touched with the code he is already using